# Add index in array

Tags: javascript, arrays

i would like to add an index in my array:

here is my loop

```
for(j=0; j< data.data.tickets.length; j++) {
  var created_at = data.data.tickets[j].created_at;
  var tickettitle = data.data.tickets[j].subject;
  cleartab[requesterid]['tickets'] = [{"created":created_at, "titre":tickettitle}];   
}
```

And it gave me this array:
[image]

The problem is that my key in `tickets[]`is always rewrite so it is not iterate. Because my users have many tickets so every index is a ticket and every ticket have a date and a title.

Comment: if you have array of objects they always have a index. In .forEach() have callback that have been invoked with three arguments" (element, index, array)

Comment: What is a "json array"?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that you are overriding the `tickets` array on each iteration of your for loop. Try this

```
         for(j=0; j< data.data.tickets.length ;j++){
            var created_at = data.data.tickets[j].created_at;
            var tickettitle = data.data.tickets[j].subject;
            // Making sure that 'tickets' will be an array
            var arrayRef = cleartab[requesterid]['tickets'] || [];
            cleartab[requesterid]['tickets'] = arrayRef.concat([{"created":created_at,"titre":tickettitle}]);
         }
```

Comment: It says concat is not defined i'm sorry i'm new in javascript and i don't don't if it matter but this code is in an angular project

Comment: This is because on the first iteration of the loop the array does not exist yet. The more easy to read way to fix this (but arguably not the most elegant one..) is to initialise your array before you run the for loop. I've update the code.

Comment: This is not possible to declare my array before the loop because :`var requesterid = data.data.tickets[j].requester_id;` need the loop to exist is there an other way ?

Comment: Thanks a lot it work ! can you just explain your code please i want to understand and not only copy your code :) what does the pipe are doing ?

Comment: Well like I said, the problem was: 1- on each iterraion of the for loop you were creating a new array on this line: `cleartab[requesterid]['tickets'] = [{"created":created_at, "titre":tickettitle}];` What the solution does is that it "pushes" new value to your array. 2- on the first run of the loop the array is not yet created, so with: `var arrayRef = cleartab[requesterid]['tickets'] || [];` we make sure that if the array does not exist yet, we create a new one. Does that make sense ?

Comment: Well thanks a lot for your explanation it was very helpfull thanks a lot !

Answer (score 0):

This will work for you ..

```
<script>
var cleartab ={tickets :[]};
$.each(data.data.tickets, function(key,val) {
    var created_at = val.created_at;
    var tickettitle = val.subject;
    cleartab.tickets.push({"created":created_at, "title":tickettitle});
});
console.log(cleartab) 
</script>
```